# Freeswitch fails Incoming calls with 408 Recovery on timer expire

Tags: sip, freeswitch, kamailio

FS is receiving SIP Invites for Incoming calls through kamailio (we've a Kamailio + Freeswitch setup) but while forwarding the invites to another leg some calls are failing with 408 status code.

One common pattern which is observed is that this happens when the receiving SIP Server responds with 480 (It's a correlation not sure if it's the causation) but according to FS internal logs it's overriding 504 with 408

```
switch_ivr_originate.c:2168 Parsing global variables

[DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:5017 sofia/internal/<someAnotherIdentifier> setting variable [sip_route_uri]=[sip:127.0.0.1:5090]

[DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:5017 sofia/internal/<someAnotherIdentifier> setting variable [dtmf_type]=[rfc2833]

[DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:3874 Originate Resulted in Error Cause: 102 [RECOVERY_ON_TIMER_EXPIRE]

[INFO] mod_dptools.c:3518 Originate Failed.  Cause: RECOVERY_ON_TIMER_EXPIRE

[NOTICE] switch_channel.c:4857 Hangup sofia/external_prack/<someIdentifier> [CS_EXECUTE] [RECOVERY_ON_TIMER_EXPIRE]

[DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:2896 sofia/external_prack/<someIdentifier> skip receive message [PHONE_EVENT] (channel is hungup already)

[DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:650 (sofia/external_prack/<someIdentifier>) State EXECUTE going to sleep

[DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:584 (sofia/external_prack/<someIdentifier>) Running State Change CS_HANGUP (Cur 163 Tot 107259)

[DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:850 (sofia/external_prack/<someIdentifier>) Callstate Change RINGING -> HANGUP

[DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:852 (sofia/external_prack/<someIdentifier>) State HANGUP

[DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:444 sofia/external_prack/<someIdentifier> Overriding SIP cause 504 with 408 from the other leg

[DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:450 Channel sofia/external_prack/<someIdentifier> hanging up, cause: RECOVERY_ON_TIMER_EXPIRE
```

Comment: 408 is usually timeout. Check firewall, check that packets go via your server. Try topoh module.